# Azure SSO with SAML for Communities Setup

Tags: community, single-sign-on, azure

What endpoints are used for Communities when setting up Azure SSO with SAML via [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/salesforce-tutorial) steps? Particularly in reference to `Sign-on URL`, `Reply URL` and `Identifier`.

The only configuration shown is for actual Org logins but I want community login functionality. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup > Connected Apps and open your connected app.  In the SAML Login Information section, expand the For Communities subsection and you'll see the endpoints for each of your communities.

Comment: Azure is the IdP, do I need a connected app for this?